# mui grid 2 items per row

Tags: material-ui, react-tsx

I'm trying to get only 2 items per row but I keep getting them all on the same row.

```
return (
    <div>
      <Grid container item xs={12} spacing={-1}>
   
      ...
      <Grid container item spacing={2}>
      ...

          <h1> Uspar</h1>
          <Box sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
            <Box className={classes.productsWrapper}>
              {PRODUCTS.map((item, index) => (
                <Button className={classes.productItem} key={index}>
                  <img className={classes.productImage} src={item.img} />
                  <h1> {item.Title}</h1>
                  <h2> {item.Subtitle}</h2>
                  <Typography variant="body1">{item.description}</Typography>
                </Button>
              ))}
            </Box>
          </Box>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have tried

```
grit item xs{6}
```

etc.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-worker-xbtfi6?file=/src/App.js this is what i get now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call the map function outside the grid. Try this way : https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-bush-xme0f0?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks but it got really big you know a way to make it smaller?

Comment: What is it you want to shrink?

Comment: the images went really big and changign the width and height of them doesnt change it

Comment: Check again, I think you want something like this.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-worker-xbtfi6?file=/src/App.js this is what i get

Comment: solved it thank you for the help